# Fallback between datacenters

Tags: proxy, ddos, datacenter, redundancy, fallbackresource

What is the best way to do a fallback between datacenters. We have a dedicated server in one of the data centers and as our traffic increased i wanted to add more then backup i wanted redundancy and load balancing.

The thing that happened in the meantime is our hosting provider got hit with some DDOS attacks. We were not the target, somebody else was but the attackers managed to make anybody available on that hosting provider. After 2 od those DDOS attacks, the past behind particularly bad i leaved a bad taste in my mouth. I want the redundancy from two different data centers and two different hosting providers.

The only thing that i can think of is DNS fallback, but we have also non HTTP traffic.

I wanted to put something in front of everything that would route/proxy that traffic but then i have also create a redundancy for that

PS. im in europe and have to have the servers in my country because of latency.

Comment: Is your question about DDoS or about a second datacenter?

Comment: If your DNS provider supports health checks you should be able to dynamically alter the hostname->IP matching.  This need not be limited to HTTP.  Any well-written application should recheck DNS periodically.

Comment: im thinking about that. the problem is that i have some services where they ask me to give them my ip address. how can i work with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Having been in the DDoS defense industry, this is commonly referred to as 'collateral damage' when unintended targets at the same data center gets taken down. A good datacenter operator will automatically kick in protective mechanisms like blackholing routes for the intended target in order to save everyone else hosted at the datacenter, but you'll be surprised how slowly many operators react to such attacks.

Sounds like you're already hosted in multiple datacenters, so a GSLB (global server load balancing) service that operates on dynamic DNS, and directs traffic on the fly based on application health checks, datacenter reachability, and where the user is coming from would have helped you. Since it's DNS, it would work for anything that needs a name resolutions, and not just for HTTP. Companies like Dyn and Akamai have monthly services that can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need DDoS protection from ISP. This is an optional service, by which the ISP tries to monitor attacks and re-route any DDoS to blackhole.

Another datacenter cannot protect you from DDoS that is targeted at **your** service.

Comment: in first post i wrote that the whole hosting provider whas down when somebody attacked somebody. i dont trust that they have a service where they can protect me if they cannot protect themself.